# Changing SCNRenderer's PointOfView

Tags: cocoa, 3d, scenekit

I am creating an SCNRenderer from a scene with a specific point of view. I am using an SCNView to make visible my point of view and when the object scene looks like I want it I render it in an offline openGLContext to make an image out of it. This is the relevant bit of code:

```
SCNRenderer *lRenderer = [SCNRenderer rendererWithContext:openGLContext.CGLContextObj options: nil];
lRenderer.scene = self.sceneView.scene;
lRenderer.pointOfView = [self.sceneView.pointOfView clone];
[ lRenderer render ];
```

I found that the cloning of the point of view makes the renderer render the scene in exactly the same way as the SCNView does. Perfect, so far.

Now I want to tweak the point of view. For instance, I would like to set the rotation to something independent of the scene view, let's say 0. So, I do:

```
lRenderer.pointOfView.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1,1,1,M_PI_2);
```

before calling `[lRenderer render]` and this does not change a thing.

Any property I change on lRenderer.pointOfView does not seem to matter. But, if I leave out the line `lRenderer.pointOfView = [self.sceneView.pointOfView clone]` the renderer renders from a default point of view instead of self.sceneView's point of view, so there must be something in the cloned SCNNode that I can change on lRenderer.pointOfView that will have an effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that looks suspicious here is that your "cloned" point of view is not part of the scene. So I would try:

```
SCNNode *anotherPointOfView = [self.sceneView.pointOfView clone]; //clone
[[self.sceneView.pointOfView parentNode] addChildNode:anotherPointOfView]; //add to the scene (here at the same hierarchy level as the original point of view)

lRenderer.pointOfView = anotherPointOfView; //set the new point of view as the pov of the offscreen renderer
```

Comment: You probably mean `[lRenderer.scene.rootNode addChildNode: lRenderer.pointOfView]` right? self.scene does not have a pointOfView member, it is of type SCNScene.

Comment: ho no, I meant [self.sceneView.pointOfView addChildNode: anotherPointOfView]; fixed